# SailsJs: How to access model from lifecycle callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Let's say I have a model called `Twins`:

```
var model = module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
             type: 'string',
        }
    }

    afterCreate: function(twin){
        Twins.create({
             name: twin.name + 'II'
        })
    }
}
```

How do I access the `Twins` model object or, for that matter, any `Model` object within a model lifecycle callback. Simply writing `Twins` does not work in the model file.

Comment: @user3351722 has the correct answer, but if you implement it as is you'll be looking at an infinite loop as each `create` will beget another inside its `afterCreate` callback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a Model like you do it. But you missed the "exec()" at your create-function so the create would never be done.

Try this:

```
afterCreate: function(twin){
    Twins.create({
         name: twin.name + 'II'
    }).exec(function(err,item){
       if(err) return sails.log.error(err);

       console.log(item);
    });
}
```